# What is the difference between two git command git branch -d <branch_name> and git branch -D <branch_name>?

Tags: linux, git, github

when we fire command

```
git branch -D <branch_name>
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

what is the difference and how the execution of each of the command occurs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `git branch`? It's quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

The `-d` version first checks if the branch has commits which are unmerged into its upstream counterpart. If there are some, the delete is denied.

The `-D` version forces the deletion.

Check [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/10400050). Basically this is what's been said

> To delete the *local* branch use one of the following:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -d branch_name
> $ git branch -D branch_name
> ```
>
> **Note:** The `-d` option is an alias for `--delete`, which only deletes the
>   branch if it has already been fully merged in its upstream branch. You
>   could also use `-D`, which is an alias for `--delete --force`, which
>   deletes the branch "irrespective of its merged status." [Source: `man
>   git-branch`]